# Issue with Smooth Shading with Array?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shaders

[image][image][image][image]

So I've go a mesh more or less the shape of a slice of bread. I've added an array modifier and curve modifier, and connected it to said-curve to get what you see here. My issue is that when rendered after being shaded smooth, it gets that weird jagged shading issue on the side of it. Each line is where one piece connects to the next in the array. Whether I apply the array, its still there, whether I merge by distance after changes nothing, and I'm getting a headache trying to figure out what is going on. Any recommendations?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us a bit more (for example the object that gets the array, screenshot of modifiers, ...) ? Maybe your array is too big and you have multiple roundtrip ?

Comment: hello please share your file (the object itself): https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Internal faces? Do the slices have open faces?

Comment: I've added photos for the modifiers, the object I'm array-ing, as well as the shape I'm going for in order to show that it isn't looping in on itself. I also added the file link as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Like @robin-betts mentioned, there are internal faces inside the "Bread-Wall" which mess up the shading. Deleting the front and rear face of the original mesh fixes that issue.

A better way of doing this would be to remove everything but a single outline of the bread mesh, convert it to a curve (Object -> Convert) and to assign it as a "Bevel" object for your curve.
This way you

- Can fill the caps by using the checkbox instead of manually filling them
- Can adjust the "slicing rate" without being limited by the mesh width

On the other hand, if you want to go for individual slices, your current approach is already the right solution - you just need to disable the "merge" option of the array and bevel the edges of the bread mesh to give it some definition.

[image: Bread using arrays and curve profiles]

[image]